# HtLaTeX Table Footnote and Makesavenoteenv

Tags: tables, htlatex

The following minimum working sample throws an error

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{table} on input line 10 ended by \end{document}.
```

While `pdflatex` compiles without any error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{footnote}

\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{Table Caption Here.}
  \label{tab:lbl}
  \begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccc}  \hline
  &&Data3 \footnote{Data3 Footnote.}        & Data4       &&Data3& Data4       &&Data3& Data4       &&Data3& Data4       \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Any Help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What I see is that the `footnote` package (old and unmaintained) is not compatible with TeX4ht.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `footnote` package seems to be incompatible with `tex4ht`. Because `tex4ht` supports footnotes in tables by default, we don't really need services of this package, in particular patching environments with 
`\makesavenoteenv`. It insert some code at the beginning and end of the patched environment and it clashes somehow with `tex4ht` code.

Simple fix is to disable the inserted code. Save the following code as `footnote.4ht`:

```
\def\savenotes{}
\def\spewnotes{}
```

Your sample should compile correctly now:

```
make4ht filename "fn-in"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @michal.h21.The question can be closed.