# Package [footnote]: Using \makesavenoteenv with tables with [H] specifier

Tags: tables, floats, footnotes

I am attempting to allow footnotes within tabulars and tables
using `\makesavenoteenv` from the [`footnote`](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mdwtools/footnote.pdf) package.

(Method suggested in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109467/footnote-in-tabular-environment).)

Errors occur when using the `[H]` option with the table.
Is there a way around this?

```
\documentclass[crop=false,float=true,class=scrartcl]{standalone}

\usepackage{float}         % improves floating objects (graphics/tables).
\usepackage{footnote}      % enables use of footnotes in float/tabular environments

\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
a
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Error is similar to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294183/htlatex-table-footnote-and-makesavenoteenv), but is likely unrelated.

Comment: it perhaps works better with `\savenotes/\spewnotes` (or a `savenotes` environment). By the way package `footnote` has some issues (for one: incompatible with `color/xcolor`), some of which are fixed by `footnotehyper`. But your problem persists even if `footnotehyper`.