# LaTeX Error: \begin{table} on input line XXX ended by \end{document}

Tags: errors

I am facing a problem with my LaTeX code.
I receive the error message `\begin{table} on input line XXX ended by \end{document}`.
But, I have no idea what went wrong as I actually have `\end{table}` in my code.

Any help?

Here's the code:

```
\begin{document}  
  
\begin{table}[H]  
\centering  
\begin{tabular}{||c c c c c||}   
 ...  
\end{tabular}  
\caption{YYY}  
\label{table 7}  
\end{table}  
  
\end{document}
```

The used packages are the following:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}%leqno,fleqn,  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
%\usepackage{german}  
%\usepackage{emlines}  
%\usepackage{amssymb}  
\pagestyle{myheadings}\setlength{\parindent}{0em} \sloppy  
\mathindent10mm  
\usepackage{xurl}  
  
%packages for the table footnotes  
\usepackage{footnote}  
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}  
\makesavenoteenv{table}  
\usepackage{scrextend}  
  
\usepackage{hyperref}  
  
\usepackage{float}  
  
\usepackage{color}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{pdflscape}  
  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{graphics}  
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage{xcolor}  
  
\usepackage{hyperref}  
  
\usepackage[  
backend=biber,  
style=apa  
]{biblatex}  
  
%\usepackage{german}  
%\usepackage{emlines}  
%\usepackage{amssymb}  
\pagestyle{myheadings}  
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}  
\sloppy  
\mathindent10mm  
  
\graphicspath{ {./Images/} }  
  
%\oddsidemargin+25mm  
%\topmargin-5mm  
%\textwidth145mm  
%\textheight245mm  
%\footskip20mm  
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because you can't use the `H` option with `\makesavenoteenv{table}`. There are other questions on this site about this, like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/330553/201628) or [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294183/201628). If I take your code and remove the line

```
\makesavenoteenv{table}
```

from the preamble, the document compiles.

Now, do you really need (or even want) this line? It would be a good idea to make sure that you know what each line of the preamble is supposed to do, and something tells me you haven't been careful about that. For example:

- You load `graphicx`, `array` and `hyperref` twice,
- You load both `graphicx` and `graphics` and both `color` and `xcolor`, while in both cases you should really only use one of them.

Understanding what each line of the preamble is doing might certainly save you some trouble later.

Comment: Many thanks, that worked out!!!